# When is $f(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\sigma(d)$ prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisor-sum, multiplicative-function

When is $f(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\sigma(d)$ prime?

Note, $f$ is multiplicative and $\sigma(n)>1, \;n>1$. Therefore $f(n)$ is prime only when $n=p^\alpha$, with $p$ prime, $\alpha\geq1$.

Furthermore, for $n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^k p_i^{n_i}$,we have that

$f(n)=\large\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i^{n_i+2}-(n_i-2)p_i+n_i+1}{(p_i-1)^2}=\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \left(\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n_i} (n_i-j+1)(p_i)^j\right)$.

So if $n$ is $p$ is an odd prime, then $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} (n-j+1)(p)^j\equiv 0\pmod{2}$ unless $n\equiv0,1 \pmod{4}$.

If $p=2$, Then $f(2^n)=2^{n+2}-2(n+2)+n+1=2^{n+2}-n+3\equiv0\pmod2$ unless $n\equiv0\pmod2$.

So consider $f(4^m)=4^{m+1}-2m+3\equiv 0 \pmod3$ if $m\equiv2\pmod3$.

Then we should consider $f(64^k)=4^{3k+1}-6k+3$ and $f(4^{3k+1})=4^{3k+2}-6k+1$.
Now I'm not sure where to go.

To summarize, we need only consider the cases $2^{6k}$, $2^{6k+2}$ and $p^{4k},p^{4k+1}$.

Also it's prime for the least of a twin prime pair.

Comment: for $k\equiv0\pmod 7$ we have $7 \mid 4^{3k+1}-6k+3$. And from wolfram, mod seven might provide a few more

Comment: The OEIS entry https://oeis.org/A000295 for the powers of $2$ has a boatload of comments and references, but I didn't spot anything specific there about the appearance of primes.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A007429 also doesn't seem to mention anything.

Comment: @charles That's the exact sequence though :) Thanks for the links. I never know where to start/how to read from oeis though

Comment: Apparently I can't tag two people.  @barry Thanks for the link. That's a subsequence then right?

Comment: @snulty: You can search by keyword or for the first few terms (separated by commas means "in this order", so `2 3 5` means "2, 3, and 5 are in the sequence" and `2,3,5` means "2 is in the sequence, followed by 3, followed by 5". So if you know some of the terms in order you can usually find the sequence easily enough.

Comment: Just saw on an old exam paper, that this function is also $\sum\limits_{d\mid n} \frac{n}{d}\tau(d)$ haha. It makes sense. Also on the oeis link